# MongoDB C++ driver stable branch crashes in Qt application

Tags: c++, multithreading, mongodb, qt, mongo-cxx-driver

I am developing a web application using Qt 5.7.0 and the MSVC 2015 64-bit compiler. I am using Qt Creator as IDE. I managed  to build and link the mongoc, mongocxx and bsoncxx libraries with the system. These libraries have been built in release mode with the same compilers and runtimes as the Qt web application. I used version 1.9.0 of the C driver and version 3.1 of the stable C++ driver. The drivers were built according to the instructions and standard setup provided by MongoDB. I linked only the release versions of both drivers with my application.

In the debug build of my application everything works fine. However, in the release build of the web application, I manage to create an instance and connection pool in the main thread of the application but when I try to acquire a connection from this pool in a child thread, the system crashes. The exact location of the crash is indicated in the code samples below.

I am not sure if this is a bug in the driver or in my multithreaded code so I include the relevant snippets of code below. The MongoPool object is created in the main thread. The MongoConnector objects are created in the child threads when a new user request is received. Please note that I minimized the code as much as possible as requested in the comments. Any person who wishes to receive the complete application code, please contact me and I will be glad to provide it to you.

[The error message and stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJEoq.png)

[The stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x5fH.png)

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mongopool.h"

MongoPool *pool;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc,argv);

    // Initialize MongoDB
    pool = new MongoPool();

    app.exec();
}
```

---

```
#include "mongoconnector.h"

extern MongoPool *pool;

MongoConnector::MongoConnector()
{
}

bool MongoConnector::storeDocument(QString dbName,
                                   QString collectionName,
                                   QString docID,
                                   QString doc)
{

    try {
        std::cout << "Creating database connection" << "\n";

        mongocxx::pool::entry client = pool->get_connection();
        if(!client)
        {
            std::cout << "No Connection!";
        }

        std::cout << "Obtaining database and collection" << "\n";

        // HERE THE CRASH HAPPENS!!!
        mongocxx::database dataDB = client->database(dbName.toLatin1().toStdString());
        mongocxx::collection dataCollection = dataDB[collectionName.toLatin1().toStdString()];
        // ....

    } catch (const std::exception& xcp) {
        std::cout << "connection failed: " << xcp.what() << "\n";
    }

    return true;
}
```

---

```
#include "mongopool.h"

// INCLUDE STATEMENTS ARE OMITTED FOR MONGOCXX AND BSONCXX

class MongoConnector
{
public:
    MongoConnector();

    bool storeDocument(QString dbName,
                       QString collectionName,
                       QString docID,
                       QString doc);
};
```

---

```
#include "mongopool.h"

MongoPool::MongoPool()
{
    using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;

    auto uri = mongocxx::uri{mongocxx::uri::k_default_uri};
    configure(std::move(uri));

    try {
        mongocxx::pool::entry client = get_connection();

        auto admin = client->database("admin");

        document ismaster;
        ismaster << "isMaster" << 1;

        auto result = admin.run_command(ismaster.view());

    } catch (const std::exception& xcp) {
        std::cout << "connection failed: " << xcp.what() << "\n";
    }
}

void MongoPool::configure(mongocxx::uri uri) {
    class noop_logger : public mongocxx::logger {
    public:
        virtual void operator()(mongocxx::log_level, mongocxx::stdx::string_view,
                                mongocxx::stdx::string_view) noexcept {
        }
    };

    auto instance =
            mongocxx::stdx::make_unique<mongocxx::instance>(mongocxx::stdx::make_unique<noop_logger>());

    configure(std::move(instance),
              mongocxx::stdx::make_unique<mongocxx::pool>(std::move(uri)));
}

void MongoPool::configure(std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::instance> instance,
                               std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::pool> pool) {
    _instance = std::move(instance);
    _pool = std::move(pool);
}

mongocxx::pool::entry MongoPool::get_connection() {
    return _pool->acquire();
}

mongocxx::stdx::optional<mongocxx::pool::entry> MongoPool::try_get_connection() {
    return _pool->try_acquire();
}
```

---

```
// INCLUDE STATEMENTS ARE OMITTED FOR MONGOCXX AND BSONCXX

class MongoPool
{
public:
    MongoPool();

    void configure(mongocxx::uri uri);
    void configure(std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::instance> instance,
                   std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::pool> pool);
    mongocxx::pool::entry get_connection();
    mongocxx::stdx::optional<mongocxx::pool::entry> try_get_connection();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::instance> _instance;
    std::unique_ptr<mongocxx::pool> _pool;

};
```

Comment: Is this pool and other objects thread-safe to be used like this?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace ?

Comment: Why are you wrapping mongocxx classes?

Comment: Edit this down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), nobody is going to go through this massive amount of code.

Comment: I think you asked this on mongodb-dev as well. I agree with the above comments: provide the stack trace, driver versions, build information on the drivers, and use the diagnostic tools provided by your toolchain to look for undefined behavior, memory errors, and data races. An MCVE as was requested above would also be much more likely to reveal the issue.

Comment: @VTT According to the MongoDB driver documentation, the pool objects are thread-safe but the client objects acquired from the pool are not.

Comment: @blueskin I added a screenshot of the stack trace, please let me know if this is sufficient?

Comment: @RustyX The mongocxx instance and pool object need to persist for the duration of the entire application lifespan. My implementation is based on this example provided by MongoDB: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/instance_management.cpp

Comment: @acm I believe I added all information you requested, is that correct? Do you want me to also update my post on the MongoDB development forum?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Also, the answer by @blueskin below seems entirely correct to me. It should be *obvious* in the debugger if you have called through a null pool entry.

Comment: @acm the client object is not null

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the stacktrace image, and mongocxx driver code, the following code only prints "No connection" but doesn't return false (or assert or exit) if client is invalid, which is what you should do

```
if(!client)
    {
        std::cout << "No Connection!";
    }
```

So obviously, at this line `mongocxx::database dataDB = client->database(dbName.toLatin1().toStdString());` **if `client` is an invalid pointer then you will get a crash**.

Also, based on the examples (line 35 https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/examples/mongocxx/mongodb.com/usage_overview.cpp )
it would be better to write it as
`mongocxx::database dataDB = (*client)[dbName.toLatin1().toStdString()];`

Comment: I agree, this seems like the most likely explanation. Impossible to know for sure from the "stacktrace" the user posted (why do people insist on posting screenshots?). It should be obvious in the debugger if the client pointer is NULL.

Comment: @acm hmm, not sure why the op posted a screenshot, I was just looking for a stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to get the code for obtaining the database and collection working. The insertion of documents now works in both Debug and Release mode. I am aware that my solution is probably not perfect but at least it does the job for this part of the problem. I checked in the mongo shell and the insertion was indeed properly executed.

```
    auto dbNameString = dbName.toStdString();
    auto collectionNameString = collectionName.toStdString();

    char *dbNameArray = new char[dbNameString.length()+1];
    for(int i=0; i<dbNameString.length(); i++)
    {
        dbNameArray[i] = dbNameString.at(i);
    }
    dbNameArray[dbNameString.length()] = '\0';

    char *collectionArray = new char[collectionNameString.length()+1];
    for(int i=0; i<collectionNameString.length(); i++)
    {
        collectionArray[i] = collectionNameString.at(i);
    }
    collectionArray[collectionNameString.length()] = '\0';

    mongocxx::database dataDB = client->database(dbNameArray);
    mongocxx::collection dataCollection = dataDB[collectionArray];

    std::string docDB = doc.toLatin1().toStdString();
    bsoncxx::document::value obj = bsoncxx::from_json(docDB.c_str());
    std::string id = docID.toStdString();

    auto builder = bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{};
    bsoncxx::document::value doc_value = builder
            << "_id" << id.c_str()
            << "doc" << obj
            << bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;

    bsoncxx::document::view view = doc_value.view();
    auto insert_result = dataCollection.insert_one(view);
```

However, when I now try to retrieve the document from the database, this works fine in Debug mode but crashes in Release mode. When I try to access the contents of the returned object, I either get a memory access violation or a corrupted heap exception. Also when trying to print out the contents of the query result, the document is completely corrupted.

```
    auto builder = bsoncxx::builder::stream::document{};
    bsoncxx::document::value doc_value = builder
            << "_id" << id.c_str()
            << bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
    bsoncxx::document::view view = doc_value.view();

    bsoncxx::stdx::optional<bsoncxx::document::value> maybe_result =
                dataCollection.find_one(view);

    if(maybe_result)
    {
        // HERE THE CRASH HAPPENS
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(*maybe_result) << "\n";
    }
```

I carefully checked how I built the MongoCXX and MongoC libraries and they have all been built using the dynamic runtimes and in Release mode. I did not link against any static libraries because my Qt app uses the dynamic runtimes.

Could it be that Qt and MongoCXX are not compatible?

Comment: What's the stack trace in this last example?

Comment: You can't mix debug and retail builds. If you built the driver as release, you need to build your app that way too. If you built the driver as debug, build the app as debug.

Comment: The reason it is working when you pass in C style strings is because you are no longer passing std::string across an ABI.

Comment: You are also leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

I added the return statement in the conditional if block but this did not solve the problem because both the printing of the "no connection" string and the return statement are never executed ... The execution always jumps over the conditional if block ...

I also modified the database request line of code but the result remains the same ...

The question remains, why is the client acquired from the pool not usable in the child thread?

EDIT: 
Today I managed to discover that the problem has something to do with the conversion of the types used in Qt to the types used in the MongoDB driver.

When I replaced the following lines of code:

```
mongocxx::database dataDB = client->database(dbName.toLatin1().toStdString());
mongocxx::collection dataCollection = dataDB[collectionName.toLatin1().toStdString()];
```

by the following lines of code everything worked fine:

```
mongocxx::database dataDB = client->database("testdb");
mongocxx::collection dataCollection = dataDB["testcollection"];
```

I tried to convert the QString in several ways to be used as parameter for the driver method call, but did not yet manage to get it working. Anybody knows how to properly convert QString variables into a parameter for the MongoDB C++ driver?

Comment: I see nothing in your code that has anything to do with threads. Please strip this down to a *minimal* compilable example, per several requests in this thread. Ideally with no QT involved.

Comment: @acm I edited the post above to reflect my latest findings. Is this sufficient information or do I need to provide more details?

Comment: Hmm. I have an idea that this relates to lifetime of temporaries and the `view_or_value` parameter type. Perhaps the binding is not working as expected. I'm unfamiliar with `QString`, but could try capturing the result of converting to `std::string` with `auto dbStr = dbNAme.toLatin1().toStdString()`, and then moving that in the call to `database` like `client->databbase(std::move(dbStr))`. Do the same for the string passed to `database::operator[]`. Does that fix your issue? If so I'll dig into how that `QString` to `std::string` is getting bound at the call site.

Comment: @acm Today I tried your suggestion but it still gives the same crash when I write the code as you suggest in your comment ...

Comment: Well, the only next step I can think of is to write a MCVE so that I can try it on my side.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve